# Lost skyrim followers

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing and beat two bosses in the same place with the help of my follower.  I'm confident my follower did not die as a result of these battles.  After the boss battles, I teleported to White Run and found that my follower was not with me. I looked in my house, and was surprised to find she was not there.  Is there any way to get her back?  I've given her some of my best items (like an ebony weapon!). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Might want to consider using punctuations next time.

Comment: Sorry I was rushing.

Comment: Hi @tony, welcome to Arqade!  You can see this question has been closed as a duplicate, because a very similar question has been asked before.  Go check that one out, and I think you'll find it has the answers you are looking for.  Remember to upvote questions and answers you find helpful.  Also, when asking questions it's always appreciated if you can include as much detail as possible, and write in a clear fashion.  I've edited your question to try and make it more readable.

Comment: I'm sorry for that and thank you for the edit I can't explain things right.